# Exterior measure does not satisfy additivity.

Tags: measure-theory

Exterior measure $m^*$ satisfy subadditivity.
$$m^*(A\cup B) \leq m^*(A) + m^*(B).$$
But for disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ it may be that $m^*(A\cup B) < m^*(A)+m^*(B)$.
So I learned that It is one reason measurable concepts come up.
I want such disjoint sets $A$, $B$.
I guess I may find this set with respect to nonmeasurable set $N$.

Comment: By $m^*$  do you mean Lebesgue outer measure on $\mathbb{R}$? Or any outer measure?

Comment: $m*$ is Lebesgue exterior measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the famous [Vitali Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) $\mathcal V$. Then, if you set $F=[0,1]\backslash \mathcal N$, you'll get $$m^*(F\cup\mathcal V)\neq m^*(\mathcal V)+m^*(F).$$

To prove it, I give you a hint : If $m^*(F)<1$, there is an open set $O$ s.t. $m^*(O)<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a [Bernstein set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set)  $B \subset \mathbb R$.  This has the property that both $B \cap A$ and $B^c \cap A$ are nonempty for any uncountable closed subset of $\mathbb R$.  In particular, both $B$ and its complement have full outer measure: $m^*(B \cap [a,b]) + m^*(B^c \cap [a,b]) = 2 (b-a)$ for any $a < b$.